# For a relation $R$, what does this notation $R^{\circ}R$, means?

Tags: notation

For a relation $R$, what does this notation $R^{\circ}R$, means?

Can anybody please help me in identifying this notation?

Actual question is:
 For the Relation $R=\{(1,2),(2,1),(2,3),(5,3),(4,5),(5,4),(5,5)\}$, find $R^{\circ}R$.

Comment: Most probably the notation is $R\circ R$, and it means the composition of $R$ with itself.

Comment: It’s probably $R\circ R$, the composition of $R$ with itself. $\langle a,b\rangle$ is in $R\circ R$ if and only if there is a $c$ such that $\langle a,c\rangle$ and $\langle c,b\rangle$ are both in $R$. For instance, $\langle 1,2\rangle$ and $\langle 2,1\rangle$ are both in $R$, so, taking $a=1,c=2$, and $b=1$, we see that $\langle 1,1\rangle\in R\circ R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$R\circ R=\{(a, b): \mbox{ for some $c$, $aRc$ and $cRb$}.\}$

It's the relation version of composition. To see this, suppose I have a function $f$. I can represent $f$ by its *graph*, the relation $R_f=\{(a, b): f(a)=b\}$.

Then the graph of the composition, $R_{f\circ f}$, is $$R_{f\circ f}=\{(a, b): f(f(a))=b\}=\{(a, b): \exists c(aR_fc\mbox{ and }cR_fb)\}=R_f\circ R_f$$ (namely, take $c=f(a)$).

Since relations can be much more complicated than functions, though, compositions of relations can behave weirdly. However, some basic properties still hold. In particular, composition of relations is associative: $R_1\circ (R_2\circ R_3)=(R_1\circ R_2)\circ R_3$.

Comment: @ Noah Schweber: Thanks.